# Localization issue while getting text to jQuery from MVC Model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am using a jQuery plug-in to display data. The plug-in basically works on JavaScript arrays. I have written the code as below:

```
var users = [];
@foreach(MyApp.UserModel um in Model.Users)
{
    @:users.push('@um.NameSurname');
}
```

to push data into a JavaScript array. Actually this code works fine. But I have character issues. Some of the names contain Turkish characters such as "Ş", "Ğ", "Ü", "Ö" which are displayed incorrectly. For example `Ç` is converted to `&#199;`. In my code I have defined localization as :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" lang="tr" />
</head>
```

and my JavaScript code looks like

```
users.push('Test &#199;ADIR');
```

instead of

```
users.push('Test ÇADIR');
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: You can just use `var users = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Users))` to create an array from your collection property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your string to an [`IHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) to avoid razor encoding the value.

> IHtmlString represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

```
var users = [];
@foreach(MyApp.UserModel um in Model.Users)
{
    var name = new HtmlString(um.NameSurname);
    @:users.push('@name');
}
```

Or if you are if your prefer `Html.Raw()`:

```
var users = [];
@foreach(MyApp.UserModel um in Model.Users)
{
    @:users.push('@Html.Raw(um.NameSurname)');
}
```